# How to use a callable as a pytest parametrize() parameter?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to specify a callable as a `pytest.mark.parametrize()` parameter for `pytest`, so that the parameters get generated dynamically only if the test is selected to be run?

I have some expensive operations to perform in order to generate the parameters, and I only want to perform them if the test is selected to be run.

e.g.,

```
import pytest

def my_callable():
    # do expensive operations here
    return [(1, 2), (3, 6)]


# I want my_callable to be called only if test_something
# has been selected to be run
@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_parm_1,my_parm_2", my_callable)
def test_something(my_parm_1, my_parm_2):
    assert my_parm_1 * 2 == my_parm_2
```

Comment: It all seems like a small deficiency on the pytest side. Maybe it is worth considering to file a bug with pytest so that to defer evaluation of parameters to the moment when the decorated tests are run (or add a decorator parameter that does that)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want - the expensive calculation is inside the fixture which is only invoked if the test is invoked and the expensive calculation is only done once:

```
class TestSomething:

    _result = None

    @pytest.fixture()
    def my_callable(self):
        if TestSomething._result is None:
            # do expensive operations here
            TestSomething._result = [(1, 2), (3, 6)]

        def _my_callable(run_number):
            return TestSomething._result[run_number]
        return _my_callable

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("run_number", [0, 1])
    def test_something(self, run_number, my_callable):
        my_param_1, my_param_2 = my_callable(run_number)
        assert my_param_1 * 2 == my_param_2
```

Comment: While that does move the expensive operations to when the test is run, it also forces the code to know the length of the iterable returned by my_callable() in advance.  Unfortunately, I don't know the length of the iterable in advance -- the expensive operations dynamically determine the length of the iterable.  

Iteresting solution, but it doesn't quite meet my requirements.  

Additionally, this solution does not have the benefit of seeing the parameter values in the names of the tests when they are run with `pytest -v`; only the "run_number" would be seen.

Comment: @RobBednark taking into account that the number of parameters is not known, the only other thing that comes to mind is to remove `parametrize`, use the fixture as above and have a loop over groups of parameters inside the test code. Somewhat ugly, but it will work.

Comment: Yes, I considered looping over the parameters inside a single test.  I was hoping to get a `parametrize` solution where each set of parameters would be it's own test, rather than lumping them all together into a single test.

Comment: @RobBednark I've just checked another idea - use the iterable object as `my_callable` and initialize the data only when you start iterating over it, but that doesn't work either - `parametrize` loops over the list of parameters during the initialization, so the expensive calculation is performed even if the test is not selected.

Comment: After a bit more digging, I also tried the [pytest_generate_tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) hook, but it still is executed on the tests collection stage, so it's not possible to delay the data calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using `mycallable` in `@pytest.mark.parametrize` you can create a proxy:

```
def my_callable():
    # do expensive operations here
    return [(1, 2), (3, 6)]

expensive_params = [paramset for paramset in my_callable()]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_parm_1,my_parm_2", expensive_params)
...
```

Comment: Works with Python 3.6.1 and pytest 3.2.0

Comment: But what about "and I only want to perform them if the test is selected to be run"? The `expensive_params` is the global variable which will always be evaluated, even if the test is not selected, isn't it?

Comment: Agreed.  `expensive_params` is always evaluated at compile-time, whereas I want it to be evaluated only if/when the test is run.

Comment: Indeed. pytest enumerates parameters before considering to run any tests and at that point creates values ahead of time - which is exactly what we want to avoid. My answer does not address that.